# cheap paid mail forwarding service for 200-300 accounts

Tags: email

I am looking for a service which can easily forward up to 200-300 email accounts. I am ok with paying a nominal fee . I don't want to manage yet another mail server. I looked into mailroute, but its 500 US$ per month for my use case (way too expensive)

Cheap would be 10$ per hundred users. Perhaps with unlimited forwarding of email.

Comment: Define cheap. You've only defined expensive.

Comment: Did you ever find something that met the criteria you were looking for? We have a pretty similar requirement and also would like to provision the accounts via an api

Answer (score 0):

Cheapest Bet.
Run your own mail server.
Windows azure (bizspark free offer) to get a few linux vms for free.
Run iRedMail to setup postfix on ubuntu or centos in around 30 mins.

Next cheapest:
Mandrill / Sendgrid / Mailgun

Mailroute is expensive because of its virus scanning. 
Its overkill for forwarding.

Mailgun has both inbound and outbound. Can use the api to link things to actual accounts.
Sendgrid / mandrill are just for sending.

You can also use windows live domains to give your users free hotmail accounts.  This lets anyone create an email at your domain name, but if you dont advertise the fact that anyone can use your domain you can use it for private use.